# Using Eclipse with a pre-existing C Makefile

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I wrote a makefile which works fine in shell (ubuntu), but I can't manage to run it from eclipse.

I created a makefile in eclipse, which is seen under DEBUG directory of the relevent project.

In Run/Debug settings I defined in Main tab in C Application: Debug/projectname, and in Project: projectname, Build configuration:Debug. (which now I see it gives me an error of not executable file so I change it to the main.o file).

in C/C++ Build , in Builder Settings I checked use default build command and unchecked Generate Makefiles Automatically. Build directory is ${workspace_loc:/projectname}

What should I do now? How make command can be run? 
What is make target? I tried to create one and then build it, but I don't see how it connects to my makefile. Should make target be done from view target of from right click on the project?

From make target view I created new target and when I do 'build target' I get

```
make mat 
make: *** No rule to make target `main.c', needed by `main.o'.  Stop.
```

So it seems to read the right makefile, but what is "No rule to make target `main.c' "? the makefile is:

```
 mat:main.o mat.o 
gcc -ansi   -lm -Wall   mat.o   main.o  -o  mat

main.o:main.c   mat.h   def.h
gcc -ansi   -pedantic   -Wall   -c  main.c

mat.o:mat.c def.h
gcc -ansi   -pedantic   -Wall   -c  mat.c
```

Comment: Does your project have a `main.c`? If so, is it in the right place? You could try to check the makefile by running it from the terminal from inside the project build directory.

Comment: project has main.c which is inside the project. running makefile from the terminal from inside the project build directory also works fine